# How to handle different event handlers with same parent?

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, parent

The following program is actually not my project, but it makes it easier to understand what I want later in my real program.

Here a .gif to see the current functionality:
[image]

**What I want?**
I want add a label total points. Which includes the points of the checkboxes and textboxes, this should be also calculate in real time. For each group (panel)

**Where is the problem?**
I dont know how to manage this, because I'm working with two different event handlers.

Here is source:

```
namespace Test1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int chkBoxX = 10;
        int chkBoxY = 30;
        int txtBoxX = 10;
        int txtBoxY = 50;
        int panelX = 0;
        int panelY = 0;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int k = 1; k <= 3; k++)
            {

                Panel panel = new Panel();
                panel.Width = 550;
                panel.Height = 100;
                panel.Location = new Point(panelX, panelY);
                panel.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue;


                panelY += 110;

                 this.Controls.Add(panel);
                  AddElements(panel);

            }                                          

        }

        void AddElements(Panel panel) {

            Label labelChkBoxPoints = new Label();
            labelChkBoxPoints.Name = "labelChkBoxPoints";
            labelChkBoxPoints.Location = new Point(400, 30);
            labelChkBoxPoints.AutoSize = true;
            labelChkBoxPoints.BackColor = Color.White;
            labelChkBoxPoints.Font = new Font(labelChkBoxPoints.Font.FontFamily, 12, FontStyle.Bold);

            panel.Controls.Add(labelChkBoxPoints);

            Label labelTxtBoxPoints = new Label();
            labelTxtBoxPoints.Name = "labelTxtBoxPoints";
            labelTxtBoxPoints.Location = new Point(400, 50);
            labelTxtBoxPoints.AutoSize = true;
            labelTxtBoxPoints.BackColor = Color.White;
            labelTxtBoxPoints.Font = new Font(labelChkBoxPoints.Font.FontFamily, 12, FontStyle.Bold);

            panel.Controls.Add(labelTxtBoxPoints);

            Label labeltotalPoints = new Label();
            labeltotalPoints.Location = new Point(430, 40);
            labeltotalPoints.Font = new Font(labeltotalPoints.Font.FontFamily, 14, FontStyle.Bold);
      //      labeltotalPoints.Text = "10XXXXXXXXXXXX0";
            labeltotalPoints.AutoSize = true;
            labeltotalPoints.BackColor = Color.White;
                    //   labeltotalPoints.;
            panel.Controls.Add(labeltotalPoints);

            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
                checkBox.Name = String.Format("checkBox{0}", i);
                checkBox.Text = "";
                checkBox.Width = 20;
                checkBox.Height = 15;
                checkBox.Location = new Point(chkBoxX, chkBoxY);
                chkBoxX += 26;

                checkBox.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;

                panel.Controls.Add(checkBox);

            }

            for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
            {
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.Name = String.Format("textBox{0}", j);
                tb.Width = 60;
                tb.Location = new Point(txtBoxX, txtBoxY);
                txtBoxX += 80;
                tb.TextChanged += txtBox_CheckedChanged;
                panel.Controls.Add(tb);
            }

            chkBoxX -= (5 * 26);
            txtBoxX -= (5 * 80);

        }

        private void txtBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int total = 0; int points = 0; 

            foreach (object tb in ((TextBox)sender).Parent.Controls)
            {

                if (tb is TextBox)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)tb).Text))
                    {
                        if (!int.TryParse(((TextBox)tb).Text, out points))
                        {
                            ((TextBox)tb).Text = "";
                        }

                            total += points;
                    }
                }
            }

            (((TextBox)sender).Parent.Controls["labelTxtBoxPoints"]).Text = Convert.ToString(total);



        }

        private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int counter = 0;

            foreach (object cb in ((CheckBox)sender).Parent.Controls)
            {
                if (cb is CheckBox)
                {
                    if (((CheckBox)cb).Checked)
                    {
                        counter++;
                    }
                }

            }

            (((CheckBox)sender).Parent.Controls["labelChkBoxPoints"]).Text = Convert.ToString(counter);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it not working? What do you experience?

Comment: @user3956566 yes, correct.

Comment: What I would do is to create a method that is responsible to calculate a sum of all points (including checkboxes and text boxes) and call this method from both event handlers. Once the checkbox state is changed, the method is called and it enumerates required controls and their values to calculate the final value. The same will happen when textbox value is changed. Method parameters may accept group ID (which group should be processed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just calculate the sum of your "point" labels at the end of both events?
It is nice and simple(You could do it more efficiently but i don't this there is a reason... )
   Just call TotalPoints() at the end of checkBox_CheckedChanged,txtBox_CheckedChanged

```
int TotalPoints()
{
        int total = (from i in GetControlsWithPoint(this)
                     where i.Text != null && i.Text != string.Empty
                     select Convert.ToInt32(i.Text)).Sum();
       // MessageBox.Show("total" + total);
        return total;
}

List<Control> GetControlsWithPoint(Control parent)
{
        List<Control> results = new List<Control>();
        if (parent == null)
            return results;

        foreach (Control item in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (item.Name == "labelChkBoxPoints" || item.Name == "labelTxtBoxPoints")
                results.Add(item);
            results.AddRange(GetControlsWithPoint(item));
        }

        return results;

 }
```

## Update

If you only want the sum per panel all you have to do is change the TotalPoint method to search only inside your panel

```
 int TotalPoints(Panel p)
 {
        int total = (from i in GetControlsWithPoint(p) where i.Text != null && i.Text != string.Empty select Convert.ToInt32(i.Text)).Sum();
       // MessageBox.Show("total" + total);
        return total;
  }
```

And at the end of your events

```
Panel p = (((Control)sender).Parent) as Panel;
TotalPoints(p);
```

Comment: I tested this. But this will not distinguish between the panels. You can see here what I mean http://i.imgur.com/LpRTpsH.gif In panel2 it added the points of panel1, but in panel2, it should be calculate seperatly.

Comment: @Iljaminati Thought you only wanted the total sum.If you want the sum for the current panel you have to modify the method a little,I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks alot. The other answeres are to difficult for me to stand at the moment.

Comment: I only posted this answer because it's simpler than @Enigmativity's . When you are more comfortable with C# have a look a Reactive Extentions

Comment: I will take a look when I have a bit more time, but one more thing, in my real program im also working with floating numbers, i noticed that it crashes then, because of the line  select Convert.ToInt32(k.Text)).Sum() . I tried Convert.ToDouble but I noticed that this function have not the method Sum(). You have an Idea to solve this?

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else,it will work with double also.The Sum method is not related to the type.It is an extention method on IEnumerable

Comment: But TotalPoints returns int, are you sure that this will work with doubles?

Answer (score 3):

I would use Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this (NuGet "Rx-Main" & "Rx-WinForms"/"Rx-WPF").

It let's me create a couple of functions to do what you want in a fairly compact kind of way.

For the check boxes you need this function:

```
Func<IEnumerable<CheckBox>, IObservable<int>> makeCheckBoxCounter = cbs =>
    cbs
        .Select(cb => Observable.FromEventPattern(h => cb.Click += h, h => cb.Click -= h))
        .Merge()
        .Select(ep => cbs.Where(cb2 => cb2.Checked == true).Count());
```

This lets me pass a list of check boxes to the function and it returns an `IObservable<int>` that gives me an observable sequence the sum of checked check boxes.

You use it like this:

```
IDisposable checkBoxesSubscription =
    makeCheckBoxCounter(new[] { checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3, checkBox4, checkBox5, })
        .Subscribe(x => label1.Text = x.ToString());
```

I've tested this code and it works perfectly.

You can shut it down by calling the following:

```
checkBoxesSubscription.Dispose();
```

The text box version is slightly more complicated owing to the need to parse the text. It looks like this:

```
Func<IEnumerable<TextBox>, IObservable<int>> makeTextBoxCounter = tbs =>
    tbs
        .Select(tb =>
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern(h => tb.TextChanged += h, h => tb.TextChanged -= h))
        .Merge()
        .Select(ep =>
        {
            var total = 0;
            foreach (var tb2 in tbs)
            {
                var value = 0;
                if (int.TryParse(tb2.Text, out value))
                {
                    total += value;
                }
            }
            return total;
        });
```

And the subscription is this:

```
var textBoxesSubscription =
    makeTextBoxCounter(new[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, })
        .Subscribe(x => label2.Text = x.ToString());
```

I've tested both of these.

Comment: When I have more knowledge in c#, i will try this.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `TextBox`and a `static int totalTotalPoints =0;`

Add a  the `TextBlock` with each group of labels:

```
 void AddElements(Panel panel) {
    TextBlock textblock = new TextBlock();
    TextBlock.Name = "TBlock";
```

Then in each of your methods where there are changes to the points, update the `TBlock.text();`

```
 private void txtBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { ....
    total += points;
    // Implement a method to determine if points increase or decrease
    // of points change.
    // So if ( points -ve or if points +ve
    totalTotalPoints += points or -=points change;
     (((TextBlock)sender).Parent.Controls["TBlock"]).Text = Convert.ToString(totalTotalPoints);
 }

 private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { ...
    counter++;

    totalTotalPoints++;
    (((CheckBox)sender).Parent.Controls["TBlock"]).Text = Convert.ToString( totalTotalPoints);

 }
```

Ok. This should work for you.

A side note:

When creating your panels allocate them names dynamically:

```
        for (int k = 1; k <= 3; k++)
        {
            Panel panel = new Panel();
            panel.Name = k.ToString();
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Would this also work, when he have checked for example 3 checkboxes and uncheck one, so that he only counts 2?

Comment: Im using C# not Android.

Comment: Would be useful for me, when u can add this.

Comment: What I dont understand, where you distinguish between the different parents from panel1, panel2...?

Comment: Okay, thanks. But consider that the amount of panel's aren't determinated, it will be variable later in my program.